# ReferenceError: node is not defined

Tags: node.js

I am running the command './loadJson.js' but am facing this issue.

It was working fine until I tried to use this 'underscore.string/slugify'.I gave the npm install for the previous one and from then on am facing this issue.

```
element.forEach(function(elem)
{
timeStarted=moment(elem.started).fromNow();
if (timeStarted < "14 days ago")
{
console.log(elem.uri);
```

> /data/slave/jenkins/workspace/parseJson/loadJson.js:28
>   element.forEach(function(elem) ^
>
> > ReferenceError: element is not defined
> >         at Object. (/data/slave/jenkins/workspace/parseJson/loadJson.js:28:1)
> >         at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
> >         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)

This is the error I'm facing.

Comment: Can you paste the sample code here..

Comment: The error is not `node` is not defined. Its `element` not defined.

Comment: @RoyalPinto I added the sample code

Comment: What is element here, where have you got that from ?

Comment: I changed it to element.It's basically whatever I am mentioning before forEach is being shown as not defined.

Comment: Seems like you have not defined the variable on which you are calling forEach.  Just to try, what happens when you do this. `var a = []; a.forEach....`

Comment: Thanks @RoyalPinto ....Now it works fine......Instead of a initializing it, I am passing my array directly to the node.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure you set environment variable path for node.js
got to: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System->Adavnce Settings->Environment Variable->user variable: edit

**C:\Program Files\nodejs**

After that open your command prompt and run command:

**node -v**

This will return current version, It means node working fine

Comment: I checked node -v. It shows the current node version

Comment: Now go to your working directory and run npm install express, If your working directing gives node_module after running this command it means your node working fine. And also define variable for foreach like:        var your_vaiable = []; your_vaiable .forEach